# Should locks in multi threading always remain immutable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying the below code snippet which is giving expected output.But I am curious to know how many lock objects I am creating 1 or 2?

```
package com.practice;

class A{
    String lock="";

    A(String lock){
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    A(){ }

    public  void printMe(int x) {
        int counter = x;
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println(++counter);
        }
    }
}



public class MultiThreadingPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A("1");

        Thread t1=new Thread(() -> {
                a.printMe(1);
        });

        a.lock = new String();

        Thread t2=new Thread(() -> {
                a.printMe(1);
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: `a.lock = new String()` really? Why?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are actually trying to do? The code you have sets the lock before starting any of the threads, so only the later lock is used.

Comment: What do you mean by "always...immutable?" Are you asking whether a _variable_ that refers to some lock object should be a `final` variable? Are you asking whether the lock object should be an immutable object? or are you asking something else?

Comment: A `new Object()` isn't any better or worse as a lock object than a `new String()` would be, but  if you write `new Object()`, you'll have fewer other programmers scratching their heads, trying to figure out what kind of weird trick you are trying to pull.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I am trying to figure out whether it  is always  necessary to have a final clause attached to the lock object .

Comment: @Dip90 - that's an entirely different question. If the lock is an object used for ```synchronized (lock)``` then no, it's guaranteed to be released on exit from the synchronized clause.  Perhaps not if the thread were to be violently killed but that's a rare consideration, and even then, there's no automatic answer; unlocking an inconsistent data structure may be worse than leaving it permanently locked.

Answer (score 2):

Should locks in multi threading always remain immutable?  Yes.

You're using a String (any Object would do) as a lock. When you assign a new value (new String) to the lock, that means you have more than one lock instance around.  It's ok as long as all threads are synchronizing on the same lock instance, but there is nothing overt in your `class A` code to ensure that is the case.

In your actual use in the example, you're safe. Since no thread get started until after you've finished setting the lock to the third and last instance, nothing will be trying to sync on the lock until it's stable. (3 instances: the first is the initialization to the empty String; the second is to the supplied constructor argument "1"; and the third is the explicit assignment, to a different empty String).  So, though this code "works", it only works by what I refer to as "coincidence", i.e., it's not  thread-safe by design.

But let's assume a case where you start each thread immediately after you construct it. This means you'd be reassigning the lock member after t1 was running but before t2 was even created.

After a while both threads will be synchronizing on the new lock instance, but for a period around the point at which you switched the lock, thread t1 could be and probably is in the `synchronized(lock) { ... }` clause using the old lock instance.  And around that time, thread t2 could execute and attempt to synchronize on the new lock instance.

In short, you've created a timing window (race hazard) in the mechanism that you intend to use to eliminate timing windows.

You could arrange a further level of synchronization that allows you to replace the lock, but I am unable to imagine any straightforward situation where that would be necessary, useful, or sensible.  Much better to allocate one lock before any contention can occur and then stick to that one lock.

P.S. "How many locks am I creating?"  3.  Though the first two are never used.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I failed to notice the ```t1.start()``` occurred only after the lock switch.  OK, so this code is thread-safe in practice, though very confusing due to pointless lock-shuffling.  All that was needed is the first ```String lock = ""``` declaration and initialization.

Comment: Changed my answer to explain how the actual example is safe but the design is not so good.

Comment: upvoted for 1st sentence and for timing window explanation. but not quite agreeing with "any Object would do"; intention is probably to express that all objects have an implicit lock, but doesn't possibility of interning or caching make strings and numbers harder to reason about than other objects, so less attractive as locks?

Comment: @NathanHughes - Yes, I think you're right.  Any implementation that has ```lock = String("literal")``` is at risk of unexpected lock re-use, and the same is true of the Java number classes.  Best to avoid it.  I'd recommend plain old Object anyway: smaller footprint, and fewest side-effects such as from interning.

Comment: Not only that, but the lock variable should be ```final``` to protect against shooting yourself in the foot.  Thus ```final Object lock = new Object()``` (once you have decided that synchronized methods won't do for you, as appropriately observed by @AlexeiKaigorodov)

Answer (score 0):

> curious to know how many lock objects I am creating 1 or 2?

This line in your program creates a single `String` instance when the program is loaded, and both of your `A` instances start out with a reference to the same `String`.

```
String lock="";
```

This line creates a second `String` instance, because `new String(...)` *always* creates a new object, regardless of whether or not some other String with the same value has been *[interned](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-pool)*.

```
a.lock = new String();
```

Comment: I only see one ```A``` instance: ```A a = new A("1")```.  The lock in that instance takes on 3 values in succession:  empty string due to the initializer, "1" via assignment in the constructor, and empty string due to subsequent reassignment.

Comment: @another-dave D'Oh! You're right. There is only one `A` instance.  Re "literal strings," I don't remember whether the language _requires_ string literals to be pooled, but I'm pretty sure that they will be pooled in most practical JRE implementations.

Comment: I retracted that edit.  There are two String objects even if the value is the same underlying sequence of characters in memory, and synchronization is based on the identity of the String object.

Comment: @SolomonSlow JLS 3.10.5

Answer (score 0):

Should locks in multi threading always remain immutable? No.

The typical way to synchronize is to use synchronized methods, not separate locks. This approach is less error-prone and therefore preferred. It is equivalent to use current object as lock:

```
synchronized(this) {
          ...
}
```

and since `this` object is not usually immutable, we can conclude that using mutable objects as locks is a common practice.

What you are doing in your code, when you change the reference to the lock object (yes, you are changing the reference and not the lock object itself), is a very bad approach. It provokes programming errors.

Comment: The value of this never changes, how could the value of this not be immutable?

Comment: The reason why people use explicitly assigned locks is so that they can have finer-grained locking than 'this'.  I assume that people who need that should know what they're doing.  On the other hand, the OP's simple code doesn't seem to need that, at least not as presented here.  On the other other hand, incrementing a counter seems like a job for AtomicInteger, not 'synchronized'.

Comment: @alexeikaigorodov - you're right, we've been slinging 'immutable' around a little loosely.  Since the OP used a String as a lock, which is an immutable object, then he is obviously never mutating the lock; he is creating 3 different immutable locks. But the question we answered was the 'obvious but unstated' question - should the reference stored in member ```lock``` remain unchanged?